# SharePoint Maximum ListView Threshold

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

What is the maximum listview threshold that can be set on a SharePoint list? What i mean to say is, threshold above the default value that is 5000. And are there any effects on the performance of a SharePoint site if the value exceeds too much if yes then what is the workaround or a solution for this? Anybody any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comprehensive article on the same:

Designing large lists and maximizing list performance (SharePoint Server 2010)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813(v=office.14).aspx